# Laravel 5 zipArchive to Storage vs to public

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

In my Larevel app, I would like to put together some files to a zip file for the client to download. I prefer not to put the zip in the public folder. 
so I create a "tobedownload" folder in my "/storage" folder and plan to put the zip file there. but I got Whoops error:

```
"ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory"
```

My sample code is like this: (say, the file needs to be put into zip is "whatever.PNG" in the public folder. No worries, I won't use files in this location in real implementation. the example archive file is named "AllDocuments.zip" itis under storage/tobedownload folder).
      public function downloadzip(){

```
     Storage::makeDirectory('tobedownload',$mode=0775); 

   $path=storage_path('tobedownload');
   $public_dir=public_path();

   $zipFileName = 'AllDocuments.zip';


    $zip=new ZipArchive(); 

    if ($zip->open( $path. '/' .$zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE))
    {
        $zip->addFile($public_dir.'/whatever.PNG' ); //where the file needs to be add to archive
        $zip->close();

    }

}
```

But say, if I put my new zip file in the public folder,I am able to create the zip. the following example code works.
      public function downloadzip(){
       //seems everthing works if I put the archive in the public folder

```
   $public_dir=public_path();

   $zipFileName = 'AllDocuments.zip';


    $zip=new ZipArchive(); 

    if ($zip->open( $public_dir. '/' .$zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE))
    {
        $zip->addFile($public_dir.'/whatever.PNG' ); //where the file needs to be add to archive
        $zip->close();

    }

}
```

I suspect it is the permission issue but I already set the storage 0755. Thanks for any helps...  I am on Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.I think I figured it out. the folder was wrong.  when you make directory on storage. `Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory('yourfolder')` the folder you create is on `/storage/app/yourfolder` instead of on `/storage/yourfolder`.

So in my previous code, change `$path=storage_path('tobedownload');` to `$path=storage_path('app/tobedownload');` makes it work.